# How to fix glitchy transform:rotateX 3d button?

Tags: css, button, rotation

```css
#learn-more-button {
  position: relative;
  top: 69%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 18px;
  width: 185px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #009ee3;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.85s;
}
#learn-more-button:hover {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;
     border-bottom: 5px solid #c42c50;*/
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(25deg);
  transform: rotateX(25deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #0091c8;
}
```

```html
<div id="learn-more-button">Button</div>
```

I have created a button that is just a blue, flat rectangle with "learn more" text. When hovered, I want it to slightly rotate on the X axis and have a slightly darker bottom border to create the illusion of a thin box style button rotating slightly. My method does work, however it seems quite "glitchy" (for lack of a better word). To try and explain, a tiny white line appears on the border for a split second and the rotation isn't smooth. The website isn't live yet so I'm not sure how I could show this if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a solid `box-shadow` will transition a bit more gracefully than `border`.

Either way, part of the glitchy feel was that you were transitioning from no border property to a 5px border (instead of a 0px border to 5px border), so the border popped away instead of animating on mouseout. In this case, I added a 0px `box-shadow` to the button before it animates, so the transition is smoother.

```css
#learn-more-button {
  position: relative;
  top: 69%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 18px;
  width: 185px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #009ee3;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.85s;
  box-shadow: #0091c8 0 0 0;
}
#learn-more-button:hover {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;
     border-bottom: 5px solid #c42c50;*/
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(25deg);
  transform: rotateX(25deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: #0091c8 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="learn-more-button">Button</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer. Looks beautiful. Out of curiosity as something to try, is it possible to make it SLIGHTLY rotate the rotate back and forth like a wobble sort of effect?

Comment: @ColinStewart Yes, but you'd need to create a CSS keyframe animation, as the easings for `transition` are not quite that powerful (since you're really just animating from state A to state B). Here's a library that could help you: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Thanks Jon, appreciate it!